# What is the significance of 22 jumada-al-thani?

Tags: shiism, holidays

At my place (India) Shias celebrate this day by arranging dastarkhwan (various special dishes) and call it dastarkhawn of Imam Hasan(A.S)

I want to know why it is celebrated?

Comment: I searched for the day which you mentioned, but I did not find any authentic result about it. Do people (Shia) celebrate the mentioned day solely in India?

Comment: i don't know about other places

Comment: I am a shia in Iran. but I have not heard of such celebration. not this name and not any specific celebration at this date.

Comment: hmm strange ! i donno how its started in india/pak.

Comment: Unfortunately i didnt find any significanct point for that day. apparently it has not any speicific happen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer regarding the significance of 22 jumada-al-thani,**

I can say that:

As far as I know and as far as I searched, there is not any authentic source regarding the importance of 22 jumada-al-thani. And also as you see at the comment of Battle of Karbala, you can figure out that seemingly no one has heard about the mentioned day (22 Jumada-al-Thani). As a result, there seems not to be a significant subject on the mentioned day.

Comment: thanks for the answer. now i will ask our local masjid imam and post his view . if there is nothing special about this day then we must not celebrate it too.

Answer (score 0):

That is the day when Abu Bakr died. I have not heard anybody celebrating that day. It is one's choice. However Shias and non-Shias do celebrate on 22nd Rajab as niaz.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam, I'm not sure if it is arranged in any other country but in India and Pakistan Imam Hassan dastarkhawan is arranged by Shia community on 22nd Jamal-ul-Sani. As a Muslim we have to learn from two sources, one being the Quran and  second is Prophet Muhammad s.a.w life. As taught by Allah and his prophet that giving food to poor and hungry also sharing with people around you is a great deed and has lots of jaza. This was followed by our beloved Imam Ali a.s. As Imam Hassan a.s. Was oldest son he would arrange a dastarkhawan in Madina where food was offered to any traveler or poor and hungry person. Anyone and everyone could eat food from Imams place. This is where it originated from and is followed by Shia community. We arrange the dastarkhawan and as per ones choice and affordability any dish or desert can be offered. It's just a blessing and we follow it to get good deeds and ask Allah for forgiveness and have mercy on us in hardship. Also for barakat in rizq (food/earning). Below is a link for reference. Please pray for me and forgive if any mistake is made above.
 https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=11&ved=0ahUKEwj8l8-7tNTVAhXHXhQKHUlqDg0QwqsBCDEwCg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwxMQfKZwRbI&usg=AFQjCNGIAvbBVKbxmgL3Qajkk3ZmThne7g

Answer (score 0):

We celebrate this as a festival in the memory of maula hasan as grandson of prophet s. W. W.  In this day he feed poor and rich people on same dastarkhwan